# Setting the right URL to make bool false Django

Tags: python, html, django, boolean

I am sending an email to the user. I have a working link to let the user set the bool as "True". Although, I can not get the right URL to set it to False.
In views.py:

```
def confirm(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
    item.confirmed = True
    item.save()
    return HttpResponse('Item number %s  changed to true' % itemnum )

def deny(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404 (PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
    item.confirmed = False
    item.save()
    return HttpResponse('Item number %s changed to false' %itemnum)
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^(?P<itemnum>\d+)/$', views.confirm, name = 'confirm-page'), #This it to set the bool as true. I just need a url to set it as false that uses a itemnum, but somehow adds a keyword maybe such as false/56/
 )
```

I need to set a URL to let the user change it to false using a unique primary key for each item. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up your `urlpatterns` like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^confirm/(?P<itemnum>\d+)/$', 'yourapp.views.confirm', name='confirm-page'),
    url(r'^deny/(?P<itemnum>\d+)/$', 'yourapp.views.deny', name='deny-page'),
)
```

So if user visits `http://yourdomain.com/confirm/3/` then it would go to `confirm` view with `itemnum` = 3. Similarly if user visits `http://yourdomain.com/deny/5/` it would lead to view `deny` with `itemnum` = 5